# Why is my overloaded << operator not working?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how to properly overload the "<<" operator so that I can use

```
std::cout << my_object;
```

to print useful debug messages. In particular, I need to have an implementation of << for each of my subclasses, so I'm declaring << to be virtual in the superclass.

Right now I'm stuck with the following piece of code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Shape {
public:
    virtual ~Shape() { };

    virtual ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm) = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape {
    int size;
public:
    Square() { size = 10; }
    ~Square() { }

    ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm) {
        return strm << "a square with size " << size;
    }
};

int main() {
    Square *my_square = new Square();

    cout << "my_square is " << my_square << "\n";
}
```

which (I think) should be working, but doesn't. What I get when using "<<" is that the pointer value of my_square gets printed, rather than the result of the overloaded << .

```
$ ./a.out 
my_square is 0xcacc20
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: _"`Square *my_square = new Square();`"_ Why not just `Square my_square;`?

Comment: There's really no need for it. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator<<` can't be a member function. This is because of the order of the arguments. The stream has to come first.

When calling an overloaded operator, such as:

```
os << object;
```

the compiler will attempt to look up both

```
os.operator<<(object);
```

and

```
operator<<(os, object);
```

(The rules for this can be rather complex, I won't attempt to describe them here.)

Because the stream always comes on the left, your member function will never be found, since it would have to be called as:

```
object.operator<<(os);
```

You need to write a free function like:

```
ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, Square const& square) {
    return strm << "a square with size " << square.size();
}
```

(where `Square::size()` returns the `size` member).

Then you need to remember to dereference your pointer too:

```
std::cout << *my_square << '\n';
```

Although I see no reason to be dynamically allocating `my_square` in this example anyway. Just stick it on the stack as a local variable.

---

If the aim here is ultimately to be able to print *any* `Shape&`, and have the printed output follow the "real" type, you would need to create:

```
virtual std::ostream& print(std::ostream&) const = 0;
```

in the `Shape` base class, and override it in each derived class, then have a free function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shape const& shape)
{
    return shape.print(os);
}
```

---

It is often advised to make *all* binary operators on your type non-member functions, so that both arguments are treated equally, and the operation remains commutative. See Scott Meyers, *Effective C++ (3rd Edition)*, Item 24, [(or find a summary online)](http://monishgupta.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/effective-c-ed-3rd-item-24-declare-non.html).

Comment: Also OP forgot dereferencing.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thanks

Comment: @mbrandalero Added a note on making all overload binary operators non-member functions.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by others, the problem is that `operator <<` can't be member function (because of the order of arguments).  The canonical way to do this is to have `operator <<(const Shape&)` call a virtual function in `Shape`

```
class Shape {
    friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const Shape& shape);
    virtual void do_print(ostream& str) = 0;
public:
    virtual ~Shape() { };
};

ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const Shape& shape) {
    shape.do_print(str);
    return str;
}
```

Note that it *is* legal to have `do_print` be private, even though it is going to be (must be) overridden by derived classes.  You could make it protected though if you like.

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing here?

You have created operator which will get you class as a first argument and stream as the second.

```
my_square << std::cout;
```

I'd create free function and to make it dynamic I'd call some virtual method in it